# Sending a variable from HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that has an action sent to create_user.php

The create_user.php deals with the information and INSERT into a mysql table and a `header("Location: ../../register/register-2.php");` is sent.

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp,
         username,
         password) 

         VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s)",

        GetSQLValueString($username_entry, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

        if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
            header("Location: ../../register/register-2.php");

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }

        mysqli_close($link);




    }
```

I want the variables sent to the register-2.php page aswell so I can call everything back from the database table like so.

```
    require '../scripts/php/db_connect.php';

    $username_check = $_POST['username_entry'];

    if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM di_ssenisub WHERE username = '$username_check'")) {

        if($count = $result->num_rows) {

        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    }

}

echo $rows['username'];
echo $rows['password'];
echo $rows['id'];
echo $rows['timestamp'];
```

The problem is sending the variable to the next page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can send value by GET method like
 header("Location: ../../register/register-2.php?r=".$value."&c=".$value2."");

Comment: consider doing an `include '../../register/register-2.php';` instead of `header("Location: ../../register/register-2.php");`

Comment: Either you can use as @FaranAli told or use session. Don't forget to destroy once you are done with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sessions to securely store variables on the server between pages.

On the first page:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username_entry;
```

And on the second:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Can i add multiple variable into one session?

i.e - $_SESSION['username'] = $username_entry, $...., $....;

Comment: seperated with commas? $, $, $;

Comment: I would do like this:
$_SESSION['username'] = $username_entry;
$_SESSION['next_var'] = $next_var;
etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
    header("Location: ../../register/register-2.php?user=$username_entry&pass=$ashpass");
```

Change the url this way and then in the register-2 page add:

```
if(isset($_GET(user)){
    $username_entry = $_GET['username_entry'];
}else{
    $username_entry = '';
}
if(isset($_GET(pass)){
    $hashpass = $_GET['pass'];
}else{
    $hashpass = '';
}
```

even if I wouldn't send the password to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

To send the values to the next page, you have a couple of options.  The easiest way is to send the variables through the URL and use `$_GET['']` to pick them up on the next page.

for instance, something like this:

```
echo '<a href = "page2script.php?id='. $rows['id'] . '">next page</a>';
```

(or you can embed this in your header script instead of a link, which is what you seem to be doing)

and then get it on the next page like so:
     $id = $_GET['id'];

However a better and much more secure way would be to put those variables into a session, and then you could grab them like so (this is MUCH MUCH safer, as putting ids and user information into `GET` variables is fairly dangerous and could enable a malicious user (or even just about anyone who was curious) to access another person's data.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

etc... for all of your variables

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick:

```
function redirect_post($uri, array $post_data)
{
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => $post_data
        ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($data)
    return file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);;
}
```

**Warning**: Escape yout `$username_check = $_POST['username_entry'];` on register-2.php

Comment: I escaped $link as a global variable.